# Extract Nested Array into Parent Array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm working with a JSON feed that includes creative IDs in a field called 'creatives'. Some of these are individual IDs and some are multiple IDs.

For e.g. the JSON might look like:

```
0: {is_associated_creatives_in_adgroups: true,…}
creatives: ["1111", "2222", "3333", "4444",…]
16: {is_associated_creatives_in_adgroups: true, creatives: ["7777"],…}
creatives: ["7777"]
```

I'm running the following code:

```
adsAssociated = resp.data.data.filter(x=>x.is_associated_creatives_in_adgroups).map(y=>y.creatives);
```

The problem I have is that since some elements of 'creatives' are arrays with multiple values, I can't treat all the nested elements within this call as individual elements within the parent array ('creatives') itself. I tried to use:

```
adsAssociated = resp.data.data.filter(x=>x.is_associated_creatives_in_adgroups).map(y=>y.creatives.flat());
```

But this just maps the elements within the nested array as a comma-separated list mapped to the single element.

How do I get instead the expected output to map one-to-one, even the elements that are an array of multiple IDs? In other words, how do I get the JS to process it as if it were...

```
creatives: ["1111"]
creatives: ["2222"]
creatives: ["3333"]
creatives: ["4444"]
creatives: ["7777"]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the required output? Would this be required:
```[ [ '1111' ], [ '2222' ], [ '3333' ], [ '4444' ] ,
  [ '7777' ] ]``` **OR** ```[ '1111', '2222', '3333', '4444', '7777' ]```

Comment: The latter ... [ '1111', '2222', '3333', '4444', '7777' ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
adsAssociated = resp.data.data.filter(x=>x.is_associated_creatives_in_adgroups).map(y=>y.creatives.flat());
```

to this

```
adsAssociated = resp.data.data.filter(x=>x.is_associated_creatives_in_adgroups).map(y=>y.creative).flat();
```

The **adsAssociated** array needs to be flattened instead of the individual arrays.